# Load xml into extjs4 treestore

Tags: javascript, xml, extjs, extjs4

I need to load data into my treestore. My ajax request give me XML data without leaf and text attribute. How I can map them ?

```
<items>
   <item>mytext</item>
   <item>mytext2</item>
   ...
</items>
```

I know for leaf property but for text I tried mapping in my model:

```
fields: [
    { name: 'leaf' ,  type: 'boolean' , defaultValue: true } ,
    { name: 'text', mapping: 'item'}, 
]
```

and the reader in my proxy store:

```
reader: { type: 'xml',root: 'items' , record: 'item' }
```

I have all the nodes but without text =/

Please help me !

-kyrillos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an other solution :

```
fields: [
    { name: 'leaf' ,  type: 'boolean' , defaultValue: true } ,
    { name: 'text', mapping: '/' }
]
```

Comment: oh wow, I forgot you could do that with the dom query.  Nice and elegant like it should be!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code, the problem is that Extjs 4 expects a model to have sub-elements, and your xml has the data at the top most level for a model.  You will either have to restructure the xml returned to something like this:

```
<items>
   <item>
       <text>mytext</text>
   </item>
   <item>
       <text>mytext</text>
   </item>
   ...
</items>
```

And use mapping to the text node that's in there.

The other option is to create a custom mapping function that will work with your structure (not probably the way Extjs would like you to do it, but if you can't change the xml, it's the only way):

```
fields: [
    { name: 'leaf' ,  type: 'boolean' , defaultValue: true } ,
    { name: 'text', mapping: function(node){
        if(node.firstChild && node.firstChild.nodeValue)
            return node.firstChild.nodeValue;
        return "";
    }}, 
]
```